# error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>'

Tags: c++

I get this strange error. I think I have included all necessary files. What could cause this?
The error is caused by this line :

```
cin >> x >> "\n" >> y >> "\n";
```

Here is the code:

```
#ifndef ARITMETICE_H
#define ARITMETICE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "UI\comanda.h"

using namespace Calculator::Calcule;

namespace Calculator{
namespace UI{

    template<int Operatie(int, int)>
    class CmdAritmetice : public ComandaCalcule
    {

    public:
        CmdAritmetice(const string &nume) : ComandaCalcule(nume)
        {
        }

        void Execute()
        {
            cout << Nume() << "\n";
            cout << "Introduceti doua numere intregi (x, y)\n";
            int x, y;
            cin >> x >> "\n" >> y >> "\n";   // here a get the error
            cout << x << " " << Nume() << " " << y << " = " << Operatie (x,y) <<"\n";
        }
    };
}
}
#endif
```

Comment: cin >> "\n" is total nonsense

Comment: @DieterLücking: although using string literals is probably way to fragile, it would be nice if there would be a simple way to parse fixed text as there is, e.g., with `scanf()` (it is fragile because reading using a non-`const` pointer to `char` is for entirely different semantics). I don't believe that this was intended in this question, though.

Comment: @DieterLücking My guess is that the intent was to read two integers, each on its own line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `cin >> "\n"`. It purports to read user input into a string literal, which doesn't make any sense. Just drop it, make it `cin >> x >>  y;`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you expected to happen when you tried to extract data from a stream into a string literal!

Answer (score 0):

cin >> must has a writable variable in the right,
your 
   cin>>"\n" 
redirect cin to a const char* type, which is read only

in a word, just use cin>> x >> y; and the iostream will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` is object of type `istream`. This class has overloaded operator `>>` to *take input* from console and put the value into given variable. The variable must be l-value, not r-value. In short, the expression given on right of `>>` must be writable variable.

This will not work:

```
const int x;
cin >> x;
```

Simply because `x` is a `const int&`, and not `int&` which what `istream::operator>>(int&)` expects.

Going this way further, when you make a call:

```
cin >> "\n";
```

You are essentially calling `operator >> (const char*)` and not `operator >> (char*)`, and hence the error. Because of multiple overloads of `operator>>` and template code behind, the error is not clear.

*Note*: The exact signature of `operator >>` might differ, but problem is with const-ness.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to consume white spaces and one new line character (note the are flavors of new line representations), you might write a manipulator

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::istream& nl(std::istream& is) {
    typedef std::istream::traits_type traits;
    while(true) {
        traits::int_type ch;
        if(std::isspace(ch = is.get())) {
            if(ch == '\n') break;
        }
        else {
            is.putback(ch);
            // No space and no '\n'
            is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            break;
        }
    }
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream s("1\n2");
    int x, y;
    s >> x >> nl >> y >> nl;
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
    if(s.fail()) {
        // The missing '\n' after '2'
        std::cout <<"Failure\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```